# How can I prevent the ui from sometimes hanging using threads?

Tags: pyqt

main method takes no arguments. main method should read all files and folders on the hard disk. However, it seems that there is no way to execute the main method in a thread. In the beginning, it reads well, then slows down from the middle, and the QListWidget, ScanInfo, stops and prints out at once, which is strange. I want it to print smoothly. What should I do?

InfoAV.py

```
def AScanButtonClicked(self):
    set1 = Setting.fileSet
    set2 = Setting.disinfectSet
    self.iv = InfonetV('C:/', set1.checkState(), set2.checkState())
    self.window = ScanForm()
    self.iv.started.connect(self.window.show)
    self.iv.logSignal1.connect(self.window.ScanInfo.addItem)
    self.iv.logSignal1.connect(self.window.ScanInfo.scrollToBottom)
    self.iv.logSignal2.connect(self.window.ResultInfo.addItem)
    self.iv.scan()
```

IV.py

```
class InfonetV(QObject):
    started = pyqtSignal()
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    logSignal1 = pyqtSignal(str)
    logSignal2 = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, path, set1, set2, parent = None):
      ...
    ...
    def scan(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.main).start()
    ...
    def main(self):
        self.started.emit()
```

Answer (score 0):

logSinal1 is a signal to add the Item of ScanList which is QListWidget. Write time.sleep(0.05) before logSignal1 is executed. Then it runs fine.

```
time.sleep(0.05)
self.logSignal1.emit(str(fname+ " " +message))
```

Comment: However, if the amount of data to be processed exceeds 1000, gui program stops. Does anyone know how to stop it?